# What's the point of initializing a variable with the same value twice?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was reading Ben Cherry's "[JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)", and he had some example code that I didn't quite understand. Under the *Cross-File Private State* heading, there is some example code that has the following:

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {}
```

This doesn't seem to be different from writing something like this:

```
var _private = my._private || {}
```

What's happening here and how are these two declarations different?

Comment: I've locked this question to prevent it from being migrated a second time: obviously there's a confusion about what's on-topic here. I've opened a [question on our meta discussion site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/are-why-is-x-code-snippet-done-this-way-questions-on-topic) to discuss whether this question is on-topic here.

Comment: Even though this question got more action here than on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316463/why-assign-this-variable-to-itself-in-this-var-declaration), based on community consensus, I have to close this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {}
```

This line means use `my._private` if it exists, otherwise create a new object and set it to `my._private`.

More than one assignment expression can be used in a statement.  The assignment operator uses (consumes) whatever is to the right of it and produces that value as its output to the left of the variable being assigned. So, in this case, with parentheses for clarity, the above is equivalent to `var _private = (my._private = (my._private || {}))`

This case is a type of [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).  A less terse version would be:

```
if (!my._private) {
    my._private = {};
}
var _private = my._private;
```

In this case, it seems that the lazy initialization is more used for *anywhere initialization* than laziness.  In other words, all functions can include this line to safely create or use `my._private` without blowing away the existing var.

Comment: Correct, but there are two layers of this. Not only does `my._private` get set to `my._private || {}`, but `_private` gets set to the same value.

Comment: ah!  Thanks Ryan.  I understood the bit about my._private || {}  what I didn't get was the _private = my._private = my._private || {}.  So the expression after the last assignment operator is the value, the names to the left of that assignment operator are getting assigned the expression?

Comment: @JoeM05 the assignment operator uses (consumes) whatever is to the right of it and produces that value as it's output to the left of the variable being assigned. So, with parentheses for clarity, the above is equivalent to `var _private = (my._private = (my._private || {}))`

Comment: @Renesis, Your comment does a better job of answering my question then the actual answer does.  Should I accept the answer anyway?  It sort of round-about-ly lead me to understanding but then your above comment made it crystal clear.

Comment: @JoeM05 Since comments are for clarification, and that's what the comment did, I've integrated it back into the answer.